# Is correct to say: "John, there is a Mr. Smith on the phone for you"

Tags: grammar

I came across this sentence in an English exam:
"John, there is a Mr. Smith on the phone for you",

My question is that is it the right way to put it in a way like the sentence above, or it should be "John, there is Mr. Smith on the phone for you"?